# Deleting pointers objects in std list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, c++11

I've got a `std::list` of `Entity` objects (on-screen objects). In one class, `EntityContainer`, I have a list of pointers to different entities. When a `EntityContainer` is destructed, I want all of the entities in that list to be destructed as well. How can I do this, while also avoiding the iterator errors that result in deleting members of the list?

```
EntityContainer::~EntityContainer()
{
    // Destroy children
    int numChildren = children.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
    {
        Entity*& child = children.back();
        delete child;
    }
}
```

The above causes a null pointer access violation in std::list::clear(), which is called during the destruction of `EntityContainer`, as it is a member variable of that object. I would belive this is because I have deleted the objects in its list, so of course it will try to access them when deleting them. However, my problem is that if I simply leave it, and allow the list of `clear()` without explicitly deleting the objects within it, their destructors are never called. I can only assume this is because the list only destroys the pointers in the list, not the objects that the pointers are pointing to. That's mostly as assumption though - I may be wrong. What would you do?

Comment: If you need pointers for that, use smart pointers.

Comment: How is `children` defined? `std::list<Entity *>`?

Comment: That's right nneonneo.

Comment: Your access violation is not due to the list's destruction.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming `children` is defined as

```
std::list<Entity *> children;
```

you can `delete` the elements using:

```
for(auto&& child : children) {
  delete child;
}
children.clear(); // not really needed since this code is in the destructor
```

There is no issue here with invalidating any iterators because you're not actually removing any elements from the `list`, only destroying the objects the list elements point to. The `list` will still contain the same number of elements after the `for` statement completes, only they'll be pointing at invalid memory at that point.

---

But really, **don't use a container of raw pointers**. Define `children` as

```
std::list<std::unique_ptr<Entity>> children;
```

And then you can get rid of the destructor definition.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. Yeah, I realized later that the loop was dumb - mostly due to too much altering and mixing up old implementations. Regardless, it looks like Smart Pointers are the way to go. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list<Entity *>` will not attempt to access any of the pointed-to objects during destruction.

Your iterated deletion code appears wrong. What you should do is just loop over the list and delete everything:

```
for(Entity *ptr : children) {
    delete ptr;
}
```

and then leave the list to clean up (deallocating the internal list of pointers).

Comment: It doesn't like that. Throws "List iterators incompatible." No idea why. I see what you mean now though, about the list iteration. I'm afraid what's above is some slightly outdated, spliced code. The exact deletion method has changed a lot, but the question remains. It appears to apply to the errors caused by your solution as well.

Answer (score 3):

Your loop isn't calling delete on every pointer in the list. It's repeatedly calling delete only on the last pointer. That's the cause of your access violation.

`delete` won't remove anything from a `list` because it doesn't know anything about it.

You need to do something like

```
for(auto itr = children.begin(); itr != children.end(); ++itr)
{
    Entity* child = *itr;
    delete child;
}
```

Or whatever your preferred loop syntax would be.

Alternatively, you could make it a `list` of `std::unique_ptr<Entity>` so that the deallocation is managed automatically when the list is cleared or entries are erased.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is giving an error mostly because of this

```
int numChildren = children.size();
for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++)
{
    Entity*& child = children.back(); // this always returns the last element on the last, it does not remove it.  You are trying to delete an already deleted pointer
    delete child;
}
```

like it has been suggested above, try something like

```
for(auto itr = children.begin(); itr != children.end(); ++itr)
{
    Entity* child = *itr;
    delete child;
}
```